# Unable to generate DateTime field from json object to java pojo using jsonschema2pojo?

Tags: java, json

I've got the following json object:

```
{
  "period": {
    "startDate": "2016-09-01T14:39:13.884Z",
    "endDate": "2021-09-01T14:39:13.884Z"
}
```

and in my maven plugin configuration I've added

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.23</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceType>json</sourceType>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>id</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <dateTimeType>java.time.ZonedDateTime</dateTimeType>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm using Java8. However in my generated java class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "startDate",
    "endDate"
})
public class Period {

    @JsonProperty("startDate")
    private String startDate;
    @JsonProperty("endDate")
    private String endDate;
    ...
}
```

The fields' type are recognized as String. Is it possible to generate directly from json object with the right DateTime type? Or must I use json schema to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, see the maven plugin setup below. The only meaningful difference I can see is that you're using json as source and I'm using a json schema file. Can you try creating a schema file like so:

```
    {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
        "title": "My Title",
        "type": "object",
        "description": "The departure time info",
        "properties": {
            "scheduled": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time",
                "required": true,
                "description": "Scheduled time of departure."
            },
         .
         .
         .
    }
```

This is my maven plugin config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.32</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/model</sourceDirectory>
                <targetPackage>myPackage</targetPackage>
                <useJodaDates>false</useJodaDates>
                <useJodaLocalTimes>false</useJodaLocalTimes>
                <useJodaLocalDates>false</useJodaLocalDates>
                <includeJsr303Annotations>false</includeJsr303Annotations>
                <includeAdditionalProperties>false</includeAdditionalProperties>
                <dateTimeType>java.time.ZonedDateTime</dateTimeType>
                <dateType>java.time.LocalDate</dateType>
                <generateBuilders>true</generateBuilders>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```